# Materialize tabs persist active tab on page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, vue.js, materialize

I am building a single page application using vue.js with materialize and I have a navbar with tabs to navigate to different pages on my website. Materialize's tabs has an active property that displays which tab is currently selected. Every thing this far works perfectly.

This is [materialize's tabs reference](https://materializecss.com/tabs.html)

**The Issue**
If you refresh the web page the tabs active property 'resets' to its default position. So I am trying to figure out how to persist the state of the navbar's active property and then reassign it to router-link.

**My Code**

```
<ul id="tabs" class="tabs tabs-transparent" :class="{ 'navbar--color': !changeNavColor }">
        <li class="tab" id="home">
          <router-link
            id="home"
            class="link"
            :class="{ 'navbar--color': !changeNavColor }"
            to="/"
          >Home</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="tab" id="services">
          <router-link
            id="services"
            class="link"
            :class="{ 'navbar--color': !changeNavColor }"
            to="Services"
          >Service</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="tab" id="Preapproved">
          <router-link
            id="Preapproved"
            class="link"
            :class="{ 'navbar--color': !changeNavColor }"
            to="PreApproved"
          >Get Pre-Approved</router-link>
        </li>

        <li class="tab">
          <router-link
            id="cars"
            class="link"
            :class="{ 'navbar--color': !changeNavColor }"
            to="Cars"
          >inventory</router-link>
        </li>
        <li class="tab">
          <router-link
            id="testimonials"
            class="link"
            :class="{ 'navbar--color': !changeNavColor }"
            to="Testimonials"
          >Testimonals</router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

```
 if (localStorage.currentTab) {
      this.currentTab = localStorage.currentTab;
      var activeTab = document.getElementById(this.currentTab);
      activeTab.classList.add("active");
      console.log("saved");
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function(event) {
        this.currentTab = event.target.id;
        console.log(this.currentTab);
      });
    });
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".tabs").tabs();
    });
    window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.onScroll);
  },
  watch: {
    currentTab(newTab) {
      console.log("watch");
      localStorage.currentTab = this.currentTab;
    }
  }
```

any help is appreciated

Comment: Can I see a link to the live site? I don’t use vue.js but I use M plenty. I’ve never really had to persist tab states across pages but off the top of my head, I’d do it with JavaScript to programmatically open the matching ID from local storage.

Comment: Ok. So it seems to work fine for me, bar the console error, until you navigate back to the home page, when the indicator then spreads across all tabs. So a couple of things: 1) tabs are not really meant to be used as navigation links - they are for showing and hiding content on the same page. I think this is the root of your problem. 2) There should only ever be one indicator, and it moves as the tab is pressed. You have two - one is nested inside the the first li, the other is loose in the UL, as it should be. Not sure where that nested one is coming from but removing it fixes the site.

Comment: okay so i can get that glitch where the bar spread across the top to go away that just started happening cause of the last thing i tried to get the active tab to persist but idk if i am explaining myself clearly the problem is if you go to a page other than the home page the refresh the page you will stay on that page (as you should) but the bar indicating the active tab will reset to the home page you are saying there is no way set the active tab active tab

Comment: Ok I get you. So this is a router problem I guess, not sure how to fix the vue way but you just need to store the if of the current tab in local storage, then make sure you are adding active to the corresponding li. That will visually shift the indicator. I can take another look later.

Comment: okay thats fine thx for helping

Comment: I actually can't think of a way to solve this with js and css, I think you have to do it through the router - as in, update the router on a refresh. Materialize has functions for updating the indicator  - instance.updateTabIndicator() - which you could try, but the main issue is because you're not using the tab to show content, we can't access the provided function for selecting a tab - instance.select('tab_id')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up implementing this. First all of your `router-links` or `<a>` have to have unique id's

```
mounted() {
    if (localStorage.currentTab) {
      this.currentTab = localStorage.currentTab;

      var element = document.querySelector(this.currentTab);
      element.classList.add("active");
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".tabs").tabs();
      $("a").click(function(event) {
        this.currentTab = "#" + event.target.id;
        localStorage.currentTab = this.currentTab;
      });
    });
  },
  watch: {
    currentTab(newTab) {
      localStorage.currentTab = this.currentTab;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think you can use hash mechanism by using window.location.hash. You can put the data-toggle attribute in every tag anchor. And just check for `location.hash !== ''`

But the more Vue way would be through client side storage. Check the [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/client-side-storage.html) its from vue docs. Although it is for the input field but you will get the idea of how to persist info by keeping a reference in client storage and on reload getting your desired state from there onward. Hope it helps.

Comment: okay that does help but I am coming from a different programming language and I need alittle more guidance so I need to get which tab is active  from what ive read I would do something like this. ``$(".active").attr('href'));`` ? then how do I assign it back when the page reloads I get i use a life cycle hook but how do i assign the class to ``router-link``

Comment: Are you able to store it in local storage? Like you just now have to assign class  to the respective router-link, right? Storing in local storage is done?

Comment: Okay I have amended my code above and no I can not get the local storage to work I don't know why I have tried both methods that are laid out on the site

Comment: ok update so I got local storage work but now when i try to get element by id to apply the active class it returns undefined

Comment: i ended up figuring it out thank you as you where the one who led me to the answer I will give you the 100 points

Comment: I am glad you finally resolved it :). Thanks for the points.. 

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61847954/materialize-datepicker-doesnt-work-if-i-navigate-to-different-page-vue-js?noredirect=1#comment109392620_61847954

Answer (score 0):

Remove the indicator that is nested inside the first li, and the navigation works fine.

```
<ul id="tabs" class="tabs tabs-transparent">
    <li id="tab" class="tab">
        <a href="/" class="link router-link-exact-active router-link-active active">Home</a>
        <li class="indicator"></li> <!-- THIS RANDOM NESTED INDICATOR IS THE ISSUE -->
    </li>
    <li id="tab" class="tab">
        <a href="/Services" class="link">Service</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab" class="tab">
        <a href="/PreApproved" class="link">Get Pre-Approved</a>
    </li>
    <li id="tab" class="tab">
        <a href="/Cars" class="link">inventory</a>
    </li>
    <li class="indicator" style="right: 488px; left: 0px;"></li> <!-- CORRECT INDICATOR, AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY MATERIALIZE -->
</ul>
```