# Materialize datepicker doesn't work if I navigate to different page vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, materialize

I am trying to implement a materialize datepicker in my vue.js project and so far I have gotten it to work as expected when the page initially loads and as long as I don't navigate to any other page it works perfectly. Soon as I do navigate to a different page then back to the page I have the date picker on it will no longer pop up the UI. I can see from doing some console logs that once `addEventLister` runs the initial time which is the time that datepicker works it never runs again even though mounted is ran every time I navigate to the page. I'm not sure if this is the proper behavior or not. What is causing this behavior and how do I correct it. All help is appreciated.

```
mounted() {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#datepicker");
      var options = {
        selectMonths: true,
        selectYears: 100,
        maxDate: new Date()
      };
      var instances = M.Datepicker.init(elems, options);
    });
  },
```

```
//In head
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


//In body I have tried both versions of jquery as I read some people where having success with the 
//older one I saw no difference
 <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

If I add these print statements at the end of `addEventListener`

```
console.log(`Elems: ${elems}`);
console.log(`Instances:${instances}`);
```

This is what i get on first load only after that nothing as `addEventListener` is not being executed

```
Elems: [object NodeList]
Instances:
```

Comment: You don’t need jQuery, not for the Materialize stuff anyway. Please log both elems and instances at the end of your mount, and see what is logged on both page load and when you navigate back.

Comment: I added the print statements and the results above. Before I was using Jquery initialization of materialize instead of javascript, not really relevant anymore i guess.

Comment: Hello again :). Can you put this code on jsfiddle or something for refrence. Maybe we can help better with code?

Comment: If addEventListener is not being mounted then obviously the picker won't work as it doesn't get initialised. I don't work with vue, but you need to either take the init out of the AddEventListener, or force it to run.

Comment: thank you getting rid of add event listener worked I should have been able to figure that out myself. if you post answer ill accept